# How to refresh TableView after app is about to become active?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios11

I'd like for my TableView to reloadData once my app is about to enter the foreground. I've done the following but it doesn't work:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //registering ContactsVC as an Observer
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(willEnterForeground),name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground,object: nil)
}


override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //remove ContactsVC as the observer when your view is going away
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
}

@objc func willEnterForeground() {

        print("print if willEnterForeground() is called")
        self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

The print statement in my function handler does print out on the console but the tableview wont reload.

Comment: ViewController life cycle is not affected, when app goes into background and again back to foreground. You may need to handle this with reference of application life cycle methods using AppDelegate

Comment: When the view life cycle methods are called is a little beside the point.  Why isn't the table view reloading after the print?  The answer can only be one of the following: 1) self.tableView isn't a table view, or isn't the one you're seeing in the UI, 2) it is reloading but the content is unchanged so it appears to do nothing.

Comment: About life cycle, its probably better to put the addObserver and removeObserver in viewDidLoad and dealloc.  You only want to add/remove the observer once.

Comment: ive tried a lot and nothing it working

Comment: update your method :
 func willEnterForeground(notification: NSNotification)    and in add Notification post method in AppDelegate's foreground Method.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4.1

in AppDelegate

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
   NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("ReloadNotification"), object: nil)
}
```

Then go to your desired View Controller and in ViewDidload

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.reloadData(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name("ReloadNotification"), object: nil)
```

finally, add the Notification Function in the ViewController

```
@objc func reloadData(_ notification: Notification?) {
    self.tableview.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Why not use `willEnterForegroundNotification` directly? why create a custom notification name?

Answer (score 2):

In ViewDidLoad ,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:  #selector(self.reloadData(_:)), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)

}
```

In Deinit, remove the observer,

```
deinit() {
     NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification), object: nil)
}
```

Reload the table in main dispatch queue,

```
@objc func reloadData(_ notification: Notification?) {
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
      [weak self] in 
      self?.tableview.reloadData()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to AppDelegate and Add a Notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NotificationToReload" object:nil];
```

in

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Then go to your desired View Controller and in ViewDidload add the same notification as

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(forceUpdateSkip:) name:@"NotificationToReload" object:nil ];
```

Then add the Notification Function in the same ViewController

```
-(void)forceUpdateSkip:(NSNotification*)notification{

  [tableview reloadData];

}
```

Instead of tableview replace your table Name.

Now whenever the app get enter Foreground, notification get called, table will be reloaded.

OR

Follow this option,

simply add

```
[tablename reloadData];
```

in

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with swift someone pls add swift version.

Comment: question is in Swift  not in Objective-c.

Comment: but the tag mentioned for this question is also Objective c, so that the answer might also be accepted in objective c rite ?

Answer (score 0):

try to use dispatchQueue for reloading tableview data.

Refer this link: https://www.raywenderlich.com/60749/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-1

Comment: There is no mention of reloading tableview data in that article.

Answer (score -1):

to reload the tableView, you can simply add

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

in your `viewWillAppear() method.`

Comment: ViewController life cycle is not affected, when app goes into background and again back to foreground.

Comment: the `viewWillAppear method` gets called every time when the app is about to come to the foreground.

Comment: If your app is active in background (not terminated) then view controller life cycle (viewWillAppear) is not called. I tested/checked it, just a min ago.

Comment: @Krunal kindly refer to the Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear

Comment: Please look at this now - https://im3.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-3-bc91f926a9.gif .  `viewWillAppear` is called once, during view controller loading only. Application state change (Background and Foreground) not calling `viewWillAppear`